# I try to pass the content of a paragraph element into a field of a contact form using Javascript

Tags: javascript

So the problem is this:

I try to get the text that is inside a specific paragraph with a specific id name and pass it inside a contact form .

i tried this

```
var src = document.getElementById("ptext"),
    dest = document.getElementById("inform");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dest.value = src.value;
        }};
```

Where "ptext" is the id of the element with the text of the paragraph and the "inform" is the id of the field in contact form.

The above code will trigger when the user clicks a button.

I am new in Javascript so the code above is probably wrong or faulty.

UPDATE: The HTML Code is this :

```
<p id="pext">Hello this is the text that is to be imported inside the form field</p>
```

form field:

```
<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" id="inform" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Subjext">
```

Comment: Use `.innerText` for the paragraph, `.value` is only for user inputs.

Comment: "Where ptext is the text of the paragraph" <= Just to double check, is that statement correct and "ptext" *is the text* of the paragraph, or did you typo and that should say is the **id** of the paragraph?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the clarification , i will try it out.

Comment: @Taplar Yes this was a typo . ptext is the id of the paragraph.I will correct that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were trying to do, but if you're trying to get the text of a paragraph into a form field on a button click (useful a lot of the time with hidden form fields), then here is a code snippet to help you:

```js
var src = document.getElementById("ptext");
var dest = document.getElementById("inform");
     
var getText = function () {
  dest.value = src.innerText;
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="ptext">This is some fake text that we'll put into the form.</p>
<form onsubmit="getText()">
  <label for="text">Info from paragraph:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="inform" name="text"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

To get the text that is inside specific paragraph, use

```
var src = document.getElementById("ptext").innerText;
```

To assign the value to an input field (which is what I'm assuming you are trying to do), use

```
document.getElementById("inform").value = src;
```

If you supply us with HTML element we could be even more precise.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications that really helped. i will edit the code and i will add the html code also.